# How much heme is in cooked pork and beef; why is cooked pork ("the other white meat") not red?

Tags: biochemistry, food, hematology, food-chemistry

The new video [See how Impossible Pork will make you forget about pig meat](https://youtu.be/u6MgW2dxhrc?t=40) includes a very short discussion of

1. the addition of heme to the product to make it taste like beef
2. the deep red color of a heme solution
3. that pork is not nearly as red as beef, (after cooking it's essentially off-white)

Does pork (pig/swine muscle tissue) have substantially less heme content than beef (steer/bovine muscle tissue)? If heme is contributing to the flavor of *cooked* meats (rather than raw) such as pork and beef, why do they no longer have a red color after cooking?

[image: heme is dark red, screen shot from See how Impossible Pork will make you forget about pig meat]

Comment: Note that the muscle composition of farm pigs and wild swines will be very different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes.

Pork has substantially less heme than beef (Cross et al. 2013).

[image: Graphic Pork Beef heme quantity]

As to why the red colour is lost, it is due to the Maillard reaction, by which the iron in the myglobin is oxidized from Fe(II) to Fe(III).  This results in a colour change in the meat (Tamanna & Mahmood 2015).

---

### Sources:

- Cross AJ, Harnly JM, Ferrucci LM, Risch A, Mayne ST, Sinha R. 2013. Developing a heme iron database for meats according to meat type, cooking method and doneness level. Food Nutr Sci 3(7): 905–913.
- Tamanna N, Mahmood N. 2015. Food Processing and Maillard Reaction Products: Effect on Human Health and Nutrition. International journal of food science 2015: 526762. doi:10.1155/2015/526762

Comment: Thank you for the concise yet complete and well-sourced answer!

Comment: Sorry for being so concise; in a bit of a hurry.  :)  The papers referenced are really pretty good reads if you want more info.

Comment: I'll definitely check them out tomorrow; this turns out to be pretty interesting!